# Access an AFP share from iPhone?

Tags: iphone, afp

I wonder whether it's possible to connect to an AFP (Apple Filing Protocol) share from my iPhone. I have a share in my WiFi network and would like to browse and read files on that share from my iPhone.

Is there a way to do that with the official SDK? If not, are there any libraries out there that I could use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[afpfs-ng](http://sites.google.com/site/alexthepuffin/home) is probably the closest thing to a usable AFP library, but it's GPL.  There is nothing built-into the SDK.  You'd be best off to use another protocol like WebDAV or SSH/SFTP.

Comment: can WebDAV or SSH/SFTP support AFP?

Comment: @AlexMarkman I'm not sure what you are asking. WebDAV, SSH, and AFP are all completely separate protocols.

Comment: I know, but did you suggested WebDAV for AFP or instead of AFP? I have been messing around to find the answer, how 'good reader' can access AFP, even though apple doesn't provide any API for iOS. I've tried the jaibreaking to enable support for AFP, but I want a native support/ any trick.

Comment: They have built their own AFP implementation.

Comment: It is very easy to understand and accept, but the main question remains a mystery.